# passing values to sql through check boxes and dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql

How can i pass Drop down values to sql database and also the check box for example if a user selects `English` and `maths` than the value inserted in to the database would be `1` or else the value would be `0`

```
    <form>
        <p id="p1">Select Your Year</p>
            <select id="year_sel">

             <option value="blank"></option>
                <option id="primary" value="primary">Primary</option>

                    <option value="1">Year one</option>
                        <option value="2">Year two</option>
                            <option value="3">Year Three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Math" value="Math">Math<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="English" value="English">English<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="HealthScience" value="HealthScience">Health Science<br>

<input class="sub_reg" type="submit" value="Register Subjects" />
</form>
```

this is how my database looks like
[image]

Comment: (1) Your `<select id="year_sel">` needs a `name` attribute to post -> `<select id="year_sel" name="year_sel" >`. Since you are using `<form>` the default is `get`, so you would get the selected value in `$_GET['year_sel']`. If you changed it to `<form method="post">` then you would get it in `$_POST['year_sel']`.  (2) Checkboxes are only posted if checked, so you can use `isset()` to set a value using a ternary - `$math = isset($_GET['Math']) ? 1 : 0;`. (swap `$_GET`/`$_POST` like the select).

Comment: Please post this comment as an answer so i can mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `<select id="year_sel">` needs a name attribute to post ->

```
<select id="year_sel" name="year_sel" >
```

Since you are using `<form>` the default is `get`, so you would get the selected value in `$_GET`

```
$year_sel = $_GET['year_sel'];
```

If you changed it to

```
<form method="post">
```

then you would get it in `$_POST`

```
$year_sel = $_POST['year_sel']
```

Second, checkboxes are only posted if checked, so you can use `isset()` to set a value using a ternary -

```
$math = isset($_GET['Math']) ? 1 : 0; 
$english = isset($_GET['English']) ? 1 : 0;
...[rest of your checkboxes]...
```

swap `$_GET`/`$_POST` like the select

```
$math = isset($_POST['Math']) ? 1 : 0; 
$english = isset($_POST['English']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="year_sel" name="year_sel">
       <option value="primary">Primary</option>
       <option value="1">Year one</option>
       <option value="2">Year two</option>
       <option value="3">Year Three</option>
</select>
```

on your form action something.php file use this to get the select value

```
$language = $_POST["year_sel"]; // chose whetever your form method
```

establish the database connection please do refer some tutorials (if you don't know )

write the mysqli insert command like

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO yourtable (language) VALUES ('$language')";
    mysqli_real_escape_string($sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die (mysqli_error());
```

now you can insert this value in your mysql or any database table

this is not tested

Comment: We are in 2016 - there is no reason to use `mysql_*` functions, even if just as an example. Even using `mysqli_query()` would be an improvement.

Comment: better (although technically `mysqli_real_escape_string( string $link )` and `mysqli_error( string $link )` require the `mysqli` connection link -> `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sql);`/`mysqli_error($conn)` )

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <p id="p1">Select Your Year</p>
     <select id="year_sel" name="year_sel">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <option id="primary" value="primary">Primary</option>
      <option value="1">Year one</option>
      <option value="2">Year two</option>
      <option value="3">Year Three</option>
     </select>
```

```
<?php
```

$variable = $_POST["year_sel"];
?>

> Should mention the HTML ELEMENT name to get the value.

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful here on SO. Edit your answer and explain why your code is the correct answer for the OP. Details always make it better.